# How can I enumerate all currently executing WCF operations?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I'd like to get/create a collection of all currently executing operations and select metadata (available from OperationContext).

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom trace listener and listen to all interesting events (once tracing is enabled http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) ?

Comment: I've created an IDispatchMessageInspector.  Its AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply methods maintain a ConcurrentDictionary with currently executing request metadata.  It just seems wrong to be injecting a synchronization point at the start/end of every operation when WCF already has this data (in 1 or more objects).

Comment: If you are the one starting the execution *in code*, why not just leave a flag somewhere to show that a wcf operation is running?

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/30/async-operations-in-wcf-canceling-operations/) article, is there library to queue and eventualy cancel async opertions in WCF. It can be useful in your case.

If you plan to build monitoring tool You can host WCF services using the appfabric framework on Windows Server. Appfabric provides an IIS extension that can be configured to trace and log WCF calls to a SQL Server DB and have monitoring dashboard in IIS admin console. More information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2010/01/11/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-with-net-4-and-windows-server-appfabric.aspx) and [here](http://jeremyronk.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/monitoring-wcf-service-with-appfabric/).